# Unable to run PHP Artisan command using Cron on Bitnami LAMP stack

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-artisan, bitnami

I've created a custom Laravel PHP Artisan command which I was intending to use together with a cron job to carry out automated tasks on my server.

However, I'm having problems running the script and have tried a whole bunch of variations without much luck. Have looked high and low on the inter webs can't find anything to remedy my problems...

Here are a few of them:

```
* * * * * sudo su daemon -s /bin/sh -c "/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apps/demo/htdocs/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/output.txt 2>&1"


* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/demo/htdocs/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/output.txt 2>&1


* * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apps/demo/htdocs/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/output.txt 2>&1
```

The error I keep getting is: "/bin/sh: 1: php: not found"

I've also tried to execute the command as Bitnami, but no luck there either.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Could you please try running the PHP binary using the whole path instead of using only "php"? You will need to replace all the calls to "php" with `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php`.

Comment: Ok, let me give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jota, I ran the following and it seemed to have done the job:

```
* * * * * cd /opt/bitnami/apps/demo/htdocs/ && /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/cron_output_8.txt 2>&1
```

Got this message instead now:

No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Which is good, I think that's just laravel, and I haven't set all that stuff up to run at this point.

Cheers,
Mikael